# How do I use variable variable names in Actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, variables, actionscript-2

I'm looping over an array named *shopData* and need to use values within that array to create new variables.
Inside the loop, I'm trying something like this:

`shop_(shopData[i].shopName).keyword = shopData[i].keyword;`

but I'm having trouble with the portion in () and can't seem to find the right syntax for this.

Assuming *shopData[i].shopName = "foo"* I need to create a variable named:

`shop_foo.keyword = value`

or if *shopData[i].shopName = "orange"*:

`shop_orange.keyword = value`

Is this even possible with AS2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  You have to create a string representation of the variable name and use [ ] brackets:

```
this["shop_" + shopData[i].shopName].keyword = shopData[i].keyword;
```

All `shop_...` variables must either be member variables of a class instance (they are members of `this` in the above example) or you have to create a simple Object container:

```
var shops:Object = {};
shops["shop_" + shopData[i].shopName].keyword = shopData[i].keyword;
```

Just writing `["shop_" + shopData[i].shopName]` to access a local variable will not compile.